# How can i call a server side button click function from client side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a server side function

```
protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       
{

}
```

I need to call the same from a client side script

```
function calSearch()
{
    // here I need to call the client side script
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cant do this, your option is to simulate Click of a button using javascript.

```
<asp:Button ID="savebtn" runat="server" OnClick="savebtn_Click" style="display:none" />
```

HTML markup will look like this:

```
<button id="btnsave" onclick="fncsave()">Save</button>
```

now simulate a Click using JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function fncsave()
     {
        document.getElementById('<%= savebtn.ClientID %>').click();
     }
</script>
```

Other solution would be to use ajax.

Comment: This works best and is the shortest way of going about server-side click, Thanks :) http://i.imgur.com/XxvWwO6.png

Answer (score 2):

you can use __doPostBack method

```
function functionName()
{

__doPostBack('ButtonId','OnClick');

}
```

or you can try this....

```
<button id="btnsave" onclick="callfunction()">Save</button>// to all javascript
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" style="display:none" />


<script type="text/javascript">
     function callfunction()
     {  
         /*do your javascript coding here*/
        document.getElementById('<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').click();
       // we are firing onClick event for  asp button btnsave form javascript.
     }
</script>
```

otherwise you can create WebMethod in code behind and make AJAX call but then you wont be able to access asp control in WebMethod.

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "AspDotNetPage{}'{"+myData+"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
               alert(msg);                
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Id of your button is **SearchButton** , you can do this

```
function calSearch(){

__doPostBack('SearchButton','');

}
```

Note: There are two underscores before doPostBack() function

[**A better way to do this here**](http://www.aaronkjackson.com/2009/05/calling-a-button-click-from-javascript-in-aspnet/)